# How do I log out from Dart's pub package manager?

Tags: dart

I have uploaded packages to [pub.dartlang.org](https://pub.dartlang.org) under two different accounts (one of them work-related, the other personal).

The `pub` command line tool doesn't have any option to select with which account to publish, so once I log on with the tool, and try to upload a package that belongs to the other account, I see:

```
$ pub publish
UnauthorizedAccess: Unauthorized user: ___@example.com is not allowed to upload versions to package xyz..
```

How do I publish with a specific account? Failing that, how do I log out the `pub` tool in order to log on again under a different account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way in the command line `pub` tool to upload under different credentials (although there is a [proposal](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1471)).

If you have a fairly recent version of `pub`, you can log out with:

```
$ pub logout
```

Then try `pub publish` again. The tool will ask you for new credentials.

---

#### Could not find a command named "logout".

The `pub logout` command is an addition [from January 2019](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/2035). If `pub` tells you this command doesn't exist, you'll have to manually remove the credentials file.

```
$ rm ~/.pub-cache/credentials.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporarily publish with different credentials you can use a command like:

```
PUB_CACHE=~/.other_credentials_cache pub publish
```

This will create a entirely separate "profile" which is used whenever running any `pub` command with the `PUB_CACHE` environment variable pointing to a directory other than `~/.pub_cache`. If you were to `pub get` with this cache you'd get entirely separate package downloaded.

With this approach you can toggle between credentials by specifying or not specifying the different cache directory. You'll need to authenticate the first time you use the new directory.